# Flash CS6 Actionscript Shake Earthquake Effect

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a flash animation, lots of layers, symbols and motion tweens going on. I am trying to achieve a camera shake effect for EVERYTHING on the stage, that starts at a point on the timeline and lasts as long as required. I have found this similar question- [Shaking effect - Flash CS6 ActionScript3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685003/shaking-effect-flash-cs6-actionscript3-0) However it hasn't really helped me out too much, being the rookie I am.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the entire animation without the shaking effect. Then copied and pasted ALL of those frames and layers into a new symbol and placed that on the stage instead. Now you can move this symbol around on the stage and create the shake effect using motion tweens.

No scripting but I achieved the intended look